# Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[options]

Tags: angular-6

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um projeto que estava em *Angular 5* e estava migrando para o *Angular 6*, após isso, o problema abaixo começou a ocorrer, alguém da um help, por favor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]